# Add Custom Confirmation before uninstall my Application in Android

Tags: android, uninstallation

I am new in Android. I want to add one custom **Confirmation** before uninstall my **Application** in **Android**.

How I can achieve this?

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: The application `NQ Mobile Security` is calling an Activity at uninstall look at the http://i.imgur.com/Fos9N.png, http://i.imgur.com/fIZbK.png, http://i.imgur.com/cG9Hr.png and the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled by Android and thus you have no control over what happens (or when) your app is uninstalled.  In case you're worried about clean up, the data stored to the SD card and any phone setting modifications will remain after the app is uninstalled - everything else (application data/cache/shared prefs) will be deleted.

Comment: The application `NQ Mobile Security` is calling an Activity at uninstall look at the http://i.imgur.com/Fos9N.png, http://i.imgur.com/fIZbK.png, http://i.imgur.com/cG9Hr.png and the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by reuse it? if your existing data structure and logic and flow doesnt change in the application it will automatically reuse it..but if any of the steps used for saving and using it is changed then its the responsibility with the developer if it wants to reuse the data pre-existing on the device or not.

hope it helps.