# How do I complete the actual uninstall/removal of my android app using an uninstall activity?

Tags: android, package, uninstallation

I added an activity with an intent filter to intercept the uninstall of my app so I can add some additional processing/cleanup when a user uninstalls my app.  My activity get called just fine but I seem unable to complete the removal of the package from the device.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Uninstall"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="package"  />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I use the package manager to try to complete the uninstall it just pops up the same chooser dialog.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, Uri.fromParts("package", Uninstall.this.getPackageName(), null));
startActivity(intent);
```

If I am providing an alternative uninstall activity for my app how do I complete the actual uninstall of the apk from the device?

Thanks.

Comment: The application `NQ Mobile Security` is calling an `Activity` at uninstall look at the (http://imgur.com/Fos9N), (http://imgur.com/fIZbK) and (http://imgur.com/cG9Hr) and the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the reference documentation for your intents. The intent `ACTION_DELETE` has to do with the deletion of items from a container, and not of applications/packages. The intent that handles the removal of applications/packages is `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` but as the documentation states:

> An existing application package has been removed from the device. The data contains the name of the package. The package that is being (un)installed does not receive this `Intent`.

So the short answer to your question is that it cannot be done. If you play by the book, you don't need to perform additional tasks at uninstall time.

Comment: thank you for your response.  I do want to play by the book, but I also would like to handle the uninstall of my app so I can clean up data on my server and stop sending push notifications proactively.

Comment: @Mark Nuetzmann: Oh, that would be nice. However AFAIK there is no way to do it, short of having a second application listening to packages removed.

Comment: @K-ballo The application `NQ Mobile Security` is calling an Activity at uninstall look at the http://i.imgur.com/Fos9N.png, http://i.imgur.com/fIZbK.png, http://i.imgur.com/cG9Hr.png and the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android