# Start intent on package_removed

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation

I have this code for checking app uninstall:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    final String action = intent.getAction();
        if("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED".equals(action)){
        // some action
    }
```

Now I want get the start intent from the uninstalled app.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to following URLs:

- [Perform a task on uninstall in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android)
- [How to show an Activity BEFORE my app is uninstalled (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android)

The Post by Janusz is very helpful here..

> Sadly android at the moment does not give you a possibility to perform code at the moment your app is uninstalled.
>
> All the settings that are set via the SharedPreferences are deleted together with everything in the Aplication Data an Cache folder.
>
> The only thing that will persist is the data that is written to the SD-Card and any changes to phone settings that are made. I don't know what happens to data that is synchronized to the contacts through your app.

Comment: I don't explane very well my questions.
I don't wanto to know when my app is unistalled. I want to know when any app is unistalled, by the indent pagkage_removed, and know what is the indent of unistalled app.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the only way to discover this is to test this. You can use the following code to find the launch intent of an application:

```
final Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
```

where pm - is PackageManager.

To my point of view this is impossible and you'll receive launchIntent equal to `null`. But you should check this on your own.

Comment: Thanks for reply and it's could almost be a solution, but I have a database with intent of some app (I can save on database also the package) and when one app is unistalled I would delete all record for this app. The problem is to know which app is unistalled. 
So, in getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName), packageName = ???