# Know if my app is uninstalled

Tags: android, uninstallation

After a lot of research, I got to a conclusion that uninstalls can't be tracked as "Package Removed" action is not broadcasted to all the apps except the one getting uninstalled.

And then I found a way of tracking uninstalls. I saved all uninstall user information by **Sending a GCM and getting "Not Registered" error in the response**(GCM gives "Not Registered" error for devices with the app uninstalled).

So now, when I installed [Opera Max](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.max.global&hl=en) app and uninstalled it, it opened a webpage asking for "Uninstall Survey". How could they have done that?

Comment: This isn't a good question for SO. I suggest you contact the Opera Max devs and ask them.

Comment: PACKAGE_REMOVED doesn't get broadcasted to the same app which is being uninstalled. And I don't know why is it not a good question when it is specifically related to programming.

Comment: I know you might have gone through this but still check this link bcoz answer and comment gives a bit idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android

Comment: @ShadowDroid I guess I have come already come across this but not sure when. I read Mark's answer before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/pelotasplus/how-to-recognise-that-the-user-has-just-uninstalled-your-app-droidconde-2015) from Droidcon 2015 where some guys reverse-engineered how Opera Max is doing that, and see [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/pelotasplus/ActionAfterUninstall) for some example code.

Comment: Great! Can't believe they did this just to open a webpage. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro this behaviour when I uninstall Opera Max, but I believe their technique is along the following lines:

- they somehow register an event handler that will send an Intent if and when the directory that the app was installed to disappears
- that event handler survives the uninstallation of the app
- when the directory disappears the intent fires - of course they can't run their own code now (since it has been uninstalled), but they can direct you to a webpage in whatever browser is in place

I didn't have any other Opera apps installed when I tried this - if you have a second app that you also control that has not been uninstalled, then it's easy for each app to monitor the uninstallation of the other one.

I was running on Lollipop - perhaps recent versions of Android have closed what certainly feels like a security hole.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work with lollipop devices. I checked on a kitkat device.