# Android : How to Detect Uninstall of Application?

Tags: android, action, uninstallation

how to detect if user has uninstalled android application from his/her device ?
Can we call api or action when user has uninstalled android app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect Android app uninstall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall)